# MMX, 3DNow!, and SSE

Tags: operating-systems

Do OSes benefit from these things, or just games?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are a collection of "extended" instructions in the CPU.

They are used for accelerating common 'media' based operations, such as FFT (Fast Fourier Transform), Matrix transformations, and such.

The MMX and SSE are mainly geared towards working with media streams (audio and video) but have applications elsewhere.  3DNow! as the name suggests is more geared towards 3D transformations.

While the main thing to benefit are media applications and games the instructions can be used in many other applications.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's only for specially-compiled applications, mainly games, graphics, multimedia, etc. applications. OSes don't take advantage of them because they rarely need to perform Single Instruction Multiple Data (SIMD) operations (which means they would apply the same instructions on massive amounts of data).

Comment: Then why can Linux be compiled to use SSE?

Comment: Despite some meanings, that linux is just for servers and freaks, the linux-community brought up some games. Maybe they could benefit from SSE.

Comment: Scientific applications can also profitably use SSE, so if you're running such an application on Linux (quite common in my neighborhood) then  you want SSE available.  I'm not too familiar with compiling kernels from scratch, do you have any in about compiling a kernel to support SSE or not?  That might help improve the answer.

Comment: @dsolimano: Nope, I don't have experience compiling kernels either, sorry. :(